# Sending ether from list of addresses with web3.js

Tags: web3js, nodejs, web3.py, python, web3js-v1.x

I would like to read the csv text file and make a transaction via web3.js like what I did with web3.py

Here is my python code

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import os
import time
import pandas as pd

from pathlib import Path

from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider
from pathlib import Path

ipc_file = os.path.join('IPC')

sending_account = "ACC"
private_key = 'PRI'

web3 = Web3(IPCProvider(ipc_file))

addresses_df = pd.read_csv(
    'test.txt',
    header=None, names=['id', 'address', 'balance']
)

nonce_count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sending_account)

for row in addresses_df.itertuples():
    nonce_cnt = int(nonce_count)
    transaction = {
        'to': row.address,
        'value': int(row.balance),
        'gas': 21000,
        'gasPrice': 1000000000,
        'nonce': nonce_cnt
    }
    signed = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, private_key)
    TxHash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    print("Address:",row.address,"Nonce:",nonce_cnt,"TX:",TxHash.hex())
    nonce_count += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

and here is my csv file

```
0,0x843fd22c88d59e57ae1856a871a5d95e95b0a656,52500000000000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the first element in the row stand for?

Comment: Just a random number from csv, nothing special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (tested with web3.js v1.2.1):

```
const fs   = require("fs");
const os   = require("os");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const NODE_ADDRESS = "YourNodeAddress";
const PRIVATE_KEY  = "0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318";
const INPUT_FILE   = "test.txt";

async function scan(message) {
    process.stdout.write(message);
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

async function getGasPrice(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const nodeGasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const userGasPrice = await scan(`Enter gas-price or leave empty to use ${nodeGasPrice}: `);
        if (/^\d+$/.test(userGasPrice))
            return userGasPrice;
        if (userGasPrice == "")
            return nodeGasPrice;
        console.log("Illegal gas-price");
    }
}

async function getTransactionReceipt(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const hash = await scan("Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry: ");
        if (/^0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{64})$/.test(hash)) {
            const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
            console.log("Invalid transaction-hash");
        }
        else if (hash) {
            console.log("Illegal transaction-hash");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

async function send(web3, to, value, gasPrice, privateKey) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const options = {
                to      : to,
                value   : value,
                gasPrice: gasPrice,
                gas     : 21000
            };
            const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey);
            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
            return receipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            const receipt = await getTransactionReceipt(web3);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
        }
    }
}

async function run() {
    const web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);
    const gasPrice = await getGasPrice(web3);
    const lines = fs.readFileSync(INPUT_FILE_NAME, {encoding: "utf8"}).split(os.EOL);
    for (const line of lines) {
        const [id, to, value] = line.split(",");
        const receipt = await send(web3, to, value, gasPrice, PRIVATE_KEY);
        console.log(`transaction ${id} executed at block #${receipt.blockNumber}`);
    }
}

run();
```

If you have a new-line character at the end of the last line in the input file, then change this:

```
const lines = fs.readFileSync(INPUT_FILE_NAME, {encoding: "utf8"}).split(os.EOL);
```

To this:

```
const lines = fs.readFileSync(INPUT_FILE_NAME, {encoding: "utf8"}).split(os.EOL).slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: You forgot nonce_count and async function getGasPrice(web3) {, async function getTransactionReceipt(web3) { is unnessary

Comment: @ChanceHan: 1. I did not forget nonce, it is not needed (handled by the node). 2. Functions `getGasPrice` and `getTransactionReceipt` are there to help you managing the whole thing; from my personal experience, when it comes to a large batch of transactions, they prove quite useful. 3. I just gave you a full porting solution to you code; a bit a gratitude wouldn't hurt in this case (in fact, it would be quite appropriate)!

Comment: 1. counting nonce for transactions are appropriate manner in case you had a transaction on account, I've tested the script and it says low nonce from node. 2. You can hardcode the gasprice,  I prefer more simple code for maintainence. 3. Why do I need gettransactionreceipt? I only need signtransaction

Comment: @ChanceHan: Sometimes the node doesn't return a response within 720 seconds, and function `sendSignedTransaction` times out (throwing an exception). In this case, you don't know for sure whether the transaction has passed or not (in fact, neither has yet happened). For such cases, function `getTransactionReceipt` allows you (the user) to manually find the transaction hash (for example, on Etherscan), and provide it to the program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fixed code

```js
const fs   = require("fs");
const os   = require("os");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const net  = require('net');

const NODE_ADDRESS = "IPC";
const SEND_ACCOUNT = "ACC";
const PRIVATE_KEY  = "PRI";
const INPUT_FILE   = "CSV";

async function run() {
    const web3      = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS, net);
    let nonce_count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SEND_ACCOUNT);

    const lines     = fs.readFileSync(INPUT_FILE, {encoding: "utf8"}).split(os.EOL);
    for (const line of lines) {
        const [id, address, balance] = line.split(",");
        const options = {
            to       : address,
            value    : balance,
            gasPrice : 1000000000,
            gas      : 21000,
            nonce    : nonce_count
        };
        const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
        console.log("Address:",address,"Balance:",balance,"Nonce:",nonce_count);
        nonce_count++
    }
}

run();
```

Comment: TO-DO: Fix sendSignedTransaction, Use batchrequest

Answer (score 0):

How can I write a program in solidity backend to read these csv data in a getter and setter function? It would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/93148)